# Workflow rules for managing fields

Tags: workflow, validation

THere is a field on address name address ID. My requirement is once the address ID is assigned, no user will be able to edit other fields of address object.
There are 4 record types and 2 page layout. How could I make other fields read only when ID assigned by workflow. Any idea will be much appreciated please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Approach**

A more useful option is to create a recordtype say ReadOnly and assign page layouts to the recordtypes.
And a workflow to when assignedTo is changed to the not null, set record type to "readonly"

If you are looking for simple steps on how to do this for the first time:

1.) Go to Setup | Create | Workflow & Approvals | Workflow Rules | New.

2.) Then select the object you want to run the workflow on, e.g., opp'y.

3.) Click Next, give it a name, set your evaluation criteria and select the 
criteria that the rule should fire under, e.g., when picklist value is "itemA".

4.) Click "Save & Next", select a Workflow action "New Field update", give it a name and select the object "opportunity" and the field you want to update, e.g., "opportunity record type",

5.) Select the record type form list list presented.

6.) Click Save. Don't forget to go back to the rule and activate it (edit and select activate).

**Second Approach** (Not tested.Not Sure if this will work or not)

You can create a validation rule which will prevent the user from changing the record once the `addressID` field is populated.

```
AND(
   NOT(ISBLANK(addressID)),
   NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(addressID))
)
```

Comment: If I go for validation, then where I should write validation rule ?

Comment: It will be on Address object

Comment: I created 1 record type and 1 page layout with read only fields. I created WFR that NOT(ISBLANK(Ps_sequence_ID__c)) and field update to record type but it is not changing to page layout with read only field. Still I can edit .

Comment: Try logging in with user who has a profile other than System Admin.System Admin already has the access to fields even if they are read only on page layout